# Simplify $(6\sqrt{x} + 3\sqrt{y})\cdot(6\sqrt{x} - 3\sqrt{y})$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

This expression $(6\sqrt{x} + 3\sqrt{y})\cdot(6\sqrt{x} - 3\sqrt{y})$ equals: ?

Simplify the expression.

I'm tried multiplying but I'm not getting the right answer.

Comment: What did you get and why is that not the right answer?

Comment: have you used $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$ ?

Comment: @user10875 : the identity from the answer is called the _difference of two squares identity_ and it is important enough that you should memorize and recognize it.  Also, if you use "\cdot" inside dollar signs, you get $\cdot$, which looks better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ and get the answer as $36x-9y$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use $$(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2.$$